# SBT RPM package missing information from spec

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to build an RPM using SBT, there is already a Build.scala file that resides in the project folder this has:

project/Build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build { ... }
```

I then have a Packaging.scala file in project/

project/Packaging.scala

```
import sbt._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._
import sbt.Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._


object Packaging {
  val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] = packagerSettings ++ deploymentSettings ++ mapGenericFilesToLinux ++ Seq(.... ) 
}
```

Which defines name, packageSummary, version, maintainer, packageDescription, name in Rpm, version in Rpm, rpmRelease etc.

I then have in the plugins.sbt

project/plugins.sbt

```
// Plugin for sbt native package manager
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.6.4")
```

and then in the main build.sbt outside of the project area:

build.sbt

```
Packaging.settings
```

The issue is that the spec file never manages to populate any of the fields from the packaging.scala file that resides inside of the project directory. It populates the information found in Build.scala only and hence there are missing elements like summary and such alike and the version is coming from Build.scala not from Packaging.scala. I am not sure how i get the packaging.scala file to be responsible for the packaging and populate the information required for when the spec file is generated.

The command i run is

```
sbt rpm:package-bin
```